# Add fade-in effect in nested accordion

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui-accordion

I am new to jquery. I have a custom Accordion in which i'll like to add in a fade-in effect to the text when a particular header title is clicked. I tried many different ways but it did not get the results I want.

Here are my accordion codes :

**HTML**

```
  <div class="container">
  <!--Enter accordion here-->

  <ul id="cbp-ntaccordion" class="cbp-ntaccordion" style="margin-top: -92px; font-family: 'FUTURA MEDIUM'; font-weight: 300; line-height:1.5;">
  <li>
     <h3 class="cbp-nttrigger">ArtZone’s 10th Anniversary Art Exhibition 2015</h3>
     <div class="cbp-ntcontent bodytext">

           <div class="myannualcontent">
              <img src="images/Arts-House-Image.jpg" alt="" align="left" style=" margin-left: 2px;  width: 19%; margin-bottom: 20px; 
              margin-top: 20px; margin-right: 35px;"/>
              <p style="text-align: justify; padding-top: 20px; margin-left: 10px;">
                       Header text here <br /><br />
                       Join us once more as we delve into the world of our students’ creative journey express beautifully on paper. Under                            the guidance of our dedicated teachers, our students hereby present to you the fruits of their labour in their very                            distinctive way.  <br /><br />
              </p>
           <div>
      </div>
   </li>

</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
.cbp-ntaccordion > li > .cbp-nttrigger:before {
font-size: 75%;
}

.cbp-ntaccordion > li > .cbp-nttrigger:before {
content: "\36";
}
.cbp-ntaccordion > li > .cbp-nttrigger:hover:before {
content: "\35";
color: inherit;
}
.cbp-ntaccordion > li.cbp-ntopen > .cbp-nttrigger:before,
.no-js .cbp-ntaccordion > li > .cbp-nttrigger:before {
content: "\34";
color: inherit;
}

.cbp-ntsubaccordion > li > .cbp-nttrigger:before {
content: "\32";
}
.cbp-ntsubaccordion > li > .cbp-nttrigger:hover:before {
content: "\33";
color: inherit;
}
.cbp-ntsubaccordion > li.cbp-ntopen > .cbp-nttrigger:before,
.no-js .cbp-ntsubaccordion > li > .cbp-nttrigger:before {
content: "\31";
color: inherit;
}

/* Initial height is zero */
.cbp-ntaccordion .cbp-ntcontent {
height: 0;
overflow: hidden;
}

/* When its open, set height to auto */
.cbp-ntaccordion .cbp-ntopen > .cbp-ntcontent,
.cbp-ntsubaccordion .cbp-ntopen > .cbp-ntcontent,
.no-js .cbp-ntaccordion .cbp-ntcontent {

-webkit-transition: opacity 500ms ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: opacity 500ms ease-in-out;
-ms-transition: opacity 500ms ease-in-out;
-o-transition: opacity 500ms ease-in-out;
transition: opacity 500ms ease-in-out;
height: auto;
}

/* Example for media query */
@media screen and (max-width: 32em) { 

.cbp-ntaccordion {
    font-size: 70%;
}

}
```

**Javascript**

```
<script>
        $( function() {
            /*
            - how to call the plugin:
            $( selector ).cbpNTAccordion( [options] );
            - destroy:
            $( selector ).cbpNTAccordion( 'destroy' );
            */
            $('#cbp-ntaccordion').cbpNTAccordion();


           // $("cbp-ntopen").click(function () {

               /** $("#cbp-ntcontent").fadeToggle("slow",   
           "linear").find(".close").on("click", function() {
                    $(this).parents("#cbp-ntcontent").fadeIn("slow");
                    return false;
                });
            }); **/

            /** on click on any of the titles then run this codes

           $("#cbp-ntaccordion").fadeToggle("slow", "linear").find(".close").on("click", function() {
                  $(this).parents("#cbp-ntaccordion").fadeOut("slow");
                   return false;
           });
           */

        } );


</script>
```

Comment: Why isn't it possible for me to use transitions? 
I tried to apply that to .cbp-ntaccordion .cbp-ntcontent p {-webkit-transition: opacity 2s ease-in;
    -moz-transition: opacity 2s ease-in;
    -o-transition: opacity 2s ease-in;
    -ms-transition: opacity 2s ease-in;
    transition: opacity 2s ease-in; } but it doesn't work either

Comment: please prepare a demo and share it here

Answer (score 1):

I didn't understand what you expect exactly. but assume you want this.if it is not tell me what you want.

**This is your html**

```
<h3 class="dofade">ArtZone’s 10th Anniversary Art Exhibition 2015</h3>
<p class="mefade" style="display:none;">This is what you want to show</p>
```

**This is your css**
**if you are using external style, in your css file**

```
 .mefade{
   display:none;
 }
```

**This is your javascript**
**if you are using internal js**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $(".dofade").click(function(){
     $(.mefade).fadeIn(3000);//3000 meant within this ms time it shows
  });
});
</script>
```

**if you use external js add this code**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $(".dofade").click(function(){
         $(.mefade).fadeIn(3000);//3000 meant within this ms time it shows
      });
    });
```